# XPATH: Get row containing String and goto link on this row

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Below fields are in table rows of a web page. I want to basically click the "Download certificate" link but only on the row that contains "15 Jun 2017". Can anyone advise an xpath that will only goto this row

```
TestTraining1-5375  Test_training1.zip  15 Jun 2017
00:00:00    
UA-1-5375
UA-2-5375
Download certificate

TestTraining1-5375  Test_training1.zip  16 Jun 2017
00:00:00    
UA-1-5375
UA-2-5375
Download certificate
```

So i can get either using

```
//*[contains(text(),'Download certificate')]@href
```

but is there a way of getting the specific row. Not sure how to do the "and" operator in xpath

HTML code here https://prnt.sc/frx1nv

Comment: Can you share `HTML` code sample instead of simple text from webpage?

Comment: Ok edited the comment now

Comment: I see no "Download certificate" link on provided `HTML`

Comment: How do i grab the source code in firebug?

Comment: Attaching screenshot https://prnt.sc/frx1nv

Comment: Can you show more of the html - two rows both having the "Download Certificate", one desired and the other not. Be sure to expand also the "15 June 2017" & 17 nodes. Thus we could help you create an xpath saying "match the link that is in a row which has this specific date"

Comment: ok try this https://prnt.sc/fscdi5       What i need from this is to obtain the row number that contains TestTraining1-3652 and 1 July 2017. I can then just select same row with Download Certificate link.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the node that holds the text *Download Certificate* is the `<a>` itself.

The following HTML example has the same example:

```
<html>
<body>
<a id="12" href="http://google.com">
<i class="fa-download">some</i>
" Download"
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

With the following robot script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
*** Test Cases ***

TC
    Open Browser    http://localhost:8090/textnode.html    Chrome

    ${var1}    Get Text    xpath=//a
    ${var2}    Execute Javascript    return document.getElementById('12').childNodes[2].nodeValue;    

    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

You get the following result:

```
${var1} = some " Download"
${var2} = " Download"
```